# MongoDB Query array and return only father an childs that contains the value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Menus Collection on MongoDB. It has values like Permission  and Submenu.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b42c5c8a80e160a146822e1"), 
    "HasSubmenu" : "false", 
    "Icon" : "fas fa-home", 
    "MenuCode" : "PaginaInicial", 
    "MenuName" : "Página Inicial", 
    "MenuState" : "paginainicial", 
    "Permission" : 1
    "Submenu" : [ ], 
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b42c5c8a80e160a146822e2"), 
    "HasSubmenu" : "true", 
    "Icon" : "far fa-file-alt", 
    "MenuCode" : "FormulariosApoio", 
    "MenuName" : "Formularios de Apoio", 
    "MenuState" : "",
    "Permission" : 1
    "Submenu" : [
        {
            "MenuState" : "tiposassociados", 
            "MenuName" : "Tipos Associados", 
            "MenuCode" : "TiposAssociados", 
            "Icon" : "fas fa-tags", 
            "HasSubmenu" : false, 
            "Permission" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "MenuState" : "naturalidades", 
            "MenuCode" : "Naturalidade", 
            "MenuName" : "Naturalidade", 
            "Icon" : "fas fa-globe-asia", 
            "HasSubmenu" : false, 
            "Permission" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "MenuState" : "nacionalidades", 
            "MenuCode" : "Nacionalidade", 
            "MenuName" : "Nacionalidade", 
            "Icon" : "fas fa-globe-americas", 
            "HasSubmenu" : false, 
            "Permission" : 4
        },     
    ]
```

}

I need help returning, only the Menus and Submenus that has the value { "Permission" : 1 }, evend if the Menus, don`t have any Submenus

Tried this one but it doens`t ssm to work.

```
db.getCollection("menus").find({
     $and: [
        {"Submenu" : { $elemMatch : {"Permission": 1}}},
        {"Permission": 1},
     ]   
});
```

Comment: You can use `db.getCollection("menus").find({"Submenu.Permission": 1, "Permission": 1},{"Submenu.$":1});` if there is only one match in submenu. You have to use `$filter` if you are expecting more than one match.Something like `db.getCollection("menus").aggregate([
    {$match: {"Submenu.Permission": 1, "Permission": 1}},
    {$project: {
        Submenu: {$filter: {
            input: '$Submenu',
            as: 'su',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$su.Permission', 1]}
        }}
    }}
])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  try with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "Permission": 1 } },
  { "$addFields": {
    "Submenu": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$Submenu",
        "as": "submenu",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [ "$$submenu.Permission", 1 ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```